# Redefine deployment (Portainer) pvc after node failure

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, k3s, persistent-volumes

I have a home lab running k3s.

> ```
> NAME         STATUS   ROLES                         AGE    VERSION
> k8s-node-001 Ready    control-plane,master,worker   302d   v1.27.6+k3s1
> k8s-node-002 Ready    worker                        302d   v1.27.6+k3s1
> ```

I recently removed a node forcefully, since the disk stopped working.
(k8s-node-003 was the failure - now deleted from the cluster)
Unfortunately that node was running the pvc for my portainer setup.

I looked for a way to "move" the pvc to another node without much luck. So I deleted it `kubectl delete pvc portainer -n portainer`

I scaled down the portainer deployment with `kubectl scale deployment portainer -n portainer --replicas=0` and tried to scale it back up `kubectl scale deployment portainer -n portainer --replicas=1`

Inspecting the pod under deployment `kubectl describe pod portainer-858644df85-sjdbk -n portainer` I see that

> ```
> ...
>
> Events:
>   Type     Reason            Age   From               Message
>   ----     ------            ----  ----               -------
>   Warning  FailedScheduling  95s   default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: persistentvolumeclaim "portainer" not found. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling..
>   Warning  FailedScheduling  13s   default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: persistentvolumeclaim "portainer" not found. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling..
> ```

I verified that the claim is gone

`kubectl get pv -n portainer portainer`

> ```
> Error from server (NotFound): persistentvolumes "portainer" not found
> ```

`kubectl get pvc -n portainer portainer`

> ```
> Error from server (NotFound): persistentvolumeclaims "portainer" not found
> ```

I guess I should have saved the pvc and then reinstated that using a command like `kubectl get pvc --namespace portainer -o json > portainer-pvc.yaml` and then reinstated it with something like `kubectl apply -f portainer-pvc.yaml -n portainer` but 20/20 hindsight is not useful now...

Is it sufficient to find the portainer pvc definition and applying that?

### UPDATE

I found the command i used to update portainer and ran that

```sh
helm upgrade --install --create-namespace -n portainer portainer portainer/portainer \
     --set enterpriseEdition.enabled=true \
     --set tls.force=true \
     --set tls.existingSecret=portainer-tls-secret
```

which appears to have reinitialised the pvc

`kubectl get pvc -n portainer portainer`

> ```
> NAME        STATUS    VOLUME   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
> portainer   Pending                                      local-path     4m12s
> ```

...but it seems that there is some other reference to the defunct node:

> ```
> Events:
>   Type     Reason            Age    From               Message
>   ----     ------            ----   ----               -------
>   Warning  FailedScheduling  4m24s  default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 2 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling..
> ```

Is there a way to alter the configuration besides wiping the whole portainer configuration and reaapplying it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My saviour was

`kubectl edit deploy portainer -n portainer -o yaml`

changed the node name, saved the file and watched everything work